# How to get param in link by HTTP GET ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post, http-get

My link is:

> http://excample.com/default.aspx?param=1

I want to get "1" in link. And if my link is:

> http://excample.com/default.aspx?param1=1&param2=0

Please help me to get the values of param1 and param2. Thank you my friend !!!

I use ASP.NET C#

Answer (score 1):

In every Request there are `Form` and `QueryString` properties.During the `Request`,in the `Form` property it contains the values which comes after submiting the form, and in `QueryString` it contains every parameter passed by the **URL**.So you need only get the QueryString from the Request and retrieve two parameters like this

```
var param1 = Request.QueryString["param1"]
var param2 = Request.QueryString["param2"]
```

You only think like this.Almost everything you need during the request is in the **Request** property.For parameters from **query string** they are in the **QueryString** property.
For deeply knowledge see here.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784(v=vs.90).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code.

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://excample.com/default.aspx?param1=1&param2=0");
string param1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("param1");
```

OR

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Get("param1");
```

OR

```
Request.QueryString["param1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://excample.com/default.aspx?param=1");
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
var par = query.Get("param");
```

or

```
var uri = new Uri("http://excample.com/default.aspx?param1=1&param2=0");
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
var par1 = query.Get("param1");
var par2 = query.Get("param2");
```